# I'm trying to change my link color in jQuery. Why is it not working

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, hover

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
        ('this').css('color','#F60')
        });
    });
```

My intention was to have users who hover over the link have the color change from white to orange

Comment: Is `('this').css('color','#F60')` a typo or are you missing the leading `$` in your real code too?

Comment: Might be easier to do it in css: `a:hover { color: #f60 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color','#F60')
        });
    });
```

Reference: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(a).hover(function(){
    $(this).css({color: '#f60'});
});
```

Should theoretically do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about IE ≤6, you could use pure CSS ...

```
.forum:hover { background-color: #380606; }
```

---

With jQuery, usually it is better to create a specific class for this style:

```
.forum_hover { background-color: #380606; }
```

and then apply the class on mouseover, and remove it on mouseout.

```
$('.forum').hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass('forum_hover');});
```

---

If you must not modify the class, you could save the original background color in `.data()` ([Example](http://jsbin.com/azasi4/2)):

```
  $('.forum').data('bgcolor', '#380606').hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var newBgc = $this.data('bgcolor');
    $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', newBgc);
  });
```

or

```
  $('.forum').hover(
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data('bgcolor', $this.css('background-color')).css('background-color', '#380606');
    },
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor'));
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors. This should work.

```
$('a').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('color', '#F60');
});
```